# Why is add function not working in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm curious what's the difference in two functions below:

```
    void Add(T x)
    {
        if (head == nullptr)
        {
            head = (new Node<T>());
            head->set(x);
            head->set_next(nullptr);
            return;
        }
        Node<T> *temp = head;
        while (temp->get_next() != nullptr)
        {
            temp = temp->get_next();
        }
        temp->set_next(new Node<T>());
        (temp->get_next())->set(x);
        (temp->get_next())->set_next(nullptr);
    }
```

```
   void Add(T x)
    {
        Node<T> *temp = head;
        while (temp != nullptr)
        {
            temp = temp->get_next();
        }
        temp = new Node<T>();
        temp->set(x);
        temp->set_next(nullptr);
    }
```

First one works properly, second one is making segm fault. Why is that? I thought outcome should be the same, just wanted to make code a little bit shorter but I'm clearly missing something

Comment: The 2nd one does not add `temp` to the list. The `while` loop is pretty useless in that function.

Comment: so the fact that I copied head's pointer and then added new item isn't enough?

Comment: You copy `head` to `temp`, but then overwrite `temp` with `temp = temp->get_next();` and again at `temp = new Node<T>();`

Comment: Ohhh yeah now I see it! Thanks a lot

Comment: There is nothing in the 2nd code that should be segfaulting (leaking though, yes), however its `while` loop is completely useless, because `temp` always ends up being `nullptr` before the new `Node` is created. The correct way to simplify the function would be more like this: `void Add(T x) { Node<T> **temp = &head; while (*temp) { temp = &((*temp)->next); } *temp = new Node<T>(); (*temp)->set(x); (*temp)->set_next(nullptr); }` Which can be simplified further if `Node` has a constructor that takes `x` as input and sets the `next` to `nullptr`, eg: `*temp = new Node<T>(x);`

Comment: The second version could segfault if head was not initialized as nullptr before, thus not being nullptr but no valid pointer too, which would cause a segfault when using it with get_next(). Beside of this, as Remy said, you never change head but only the local variable temp.